# On change event does not fire with javascript input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area that I want to fire an event everytime a change occurs. I wrote the on input event and the change event fires perfectly when I use my keyboard to input changes. However, I am in the process of designing a custom keyboard for mobile devices. As you can see below, if I use the custom keyboard which uses javascript to enter values to the text area the change event does not fire at all.

Is there a way to track change event when input is done through javascript?

```js
 $('#main').on('input','.use-keyboard-input',function(){
  alert(`On input event fired`)
  

 })



const Keyboard = {
    elements: {
        main: null,
        keysContainer: null,
        keys: []
    },

    eventHandlers: {
        oninput: null,
        onclose: null
    },

    properties: {
        value: "",
        capsLock: false
    },

    init() {
        // Create main elements
        this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
        this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

        // Setup main elements
        this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
        this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
        this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys());

        this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");

        // Add to DOM
        this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
        document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

        // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
        document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
                this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
                    element.value = currentValue;
                });
            });
        });
    },

    _createKeys() {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        const keyLayout = [
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
            "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
            "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
            "space"
        ];

        // Creates HTML for an icon
        const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
            return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
        };

        keyLayout.forEach(key => {
            const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
            const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;

            // Add attributes/classes
            keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
            keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

            switch (key) {
                case "backspace":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "caps":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this._toggleCapsLock();
                        keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
                    });

                    break;

                case "enter":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += "\n";
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "space":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += " ";
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "done":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--dark");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("check_circle");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.close();
                        this._triggerEvent("onclose");
                    });

                    break;

                default:
                    keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;
            }

            fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

            if (insertLineBreak) {
                fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        });

        return fragment;
    },

    _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
        if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
            this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
        }
    },

    _toggleCapsLock() {
        this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

        for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
            if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
                key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    },

    open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
        this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
        this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
        this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
        this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
    },

    close() {
        this.properties.value = "";
        this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
        this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
        this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
    }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    Keyboard.init();
});
```

```css
.keyboard {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #004134;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    user-select: none;
    transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
    bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
    text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
    height: 45px;
    width: 6%;
    max-width: 90px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
    width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
    width: 36%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--activatable::after {
    content: '';
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.keyboard__key--active::after {
    background: #08ff00;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Virtual Keyboard w/ HTML, CSS & JS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dcode.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="keyboard/Keyboard.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Virtual Keyboard w/ HTML, CSS & JS</h1>
    <h3>Features</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Easy to integrate</li>
        <li>Responsive</li>
        <li>Vanilla JS (<strong>no libraries required!</strong>)</li>
    </ul>
  
  
  <div id ="main">
          <textarea class="use-keyboard-input" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 30px; width: 300px;"></textarea>
  
  <textarea class="use-keyboard-input" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; right: 800px; width: 300px;"></textarea>
  </div>


    <script src="keyboard/Keyboard.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Whenever you change the textarea content just trigger the input event `$('#main').trigger('input');`.